# Как передать массив в post-запросе?

Tags: ios, swift, http, post

В `post`-запросе нужно передать массив изображений в определенном формате.
Пример: `"photos":[{"image":image1}, {"image":image2}, ...]`)

Как это сделать?

Пробовал так:

```
let image1 : UIImage = data.photos[1].image
let imageData : Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5) as! Data
let image0 : UIImage = data.photos[0].image
let imageData0 : Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image0, 0.5) as! Data


var arrDic: NSArray = [
    ["image": imageData]
    , ["image": imageData0]
]
let response = [ "fotos" : JSON(arrDic) ]

print(JSON(response))

Alamofire.request("http://www.carsapp.weblancer.by/api/adverts/create/", method: .post, parameters: response, headers: header).responseJSON { response in

    if let jsonObj = response.result.value {
        let json = JSON(jsonObj)
        let advert = Advert(from: json)
        completion(advert)
    }
}
```

Сервер возвращает:

> The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать структуру требуемого json и назови, к примеру "a". Самому не было нужды преобразовывать обратно, но, думаю, так работать будет

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: a, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

И затем отправь в теле URLRequest

Comment: а как в json запихнуть Data?

Comment: я думаю само преобразует, так как json на выходе в формате Data, а в качестве аргумента принимает формат Any